# Windows の VS Code で起動するターミナルで Git のために公開鍵をコピーしたい

Tags: cmd

freeCodeCampのYouTube動画でGitを学んでいます。

[Git and GitHub for Beginners - Crash Course (YouTube)](https://youtu.be/RGOj5yH7evk?t=1422)

[23:40 頃](https://youtu.be/RGOj5yH7evk?t=1422) の pbcopy を実施している箇所まで来たのですが、画像のように表示されてしまいました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

私はWindowsを使っているのでpbcopyは使えませんでした。なので代替としてcopyが使えるとわかりました。

加えてVSCodeでは>が認識されない？ので書いていません。

どれをどうやって変えれば良いのかわかりません。
アドバイスのご教示お願いします。

Comment: これらあたりでは？ [［clip / pbcopy・pbpaste］クリップボードにコピー](https://xtech.nikkei.com/it/atcl/column/15/042000103/080400036/), [Linux・WSL・Windows GitBash でクリップボードのコピー・ペーストを実現するコマンド](https://neos21.net/blog/2021/01/24-02.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

前回と同じで、エラーメッセージが英語でもまずは (機械翻訳にかけてでも) 読みましょう。

---

##### 1点目

`copy` で指定してるファイルが「存在しない」というエラーです。キャプチャ画面を見る限りは
作業フォルダ直下に `testkey`, `testkey.pub` が存在するのではないでしょうか？

```
Copy-Item: Cannot find path 'C:\Users\FMV\.ssh\testkey'
```

##### 2点目

`pbcopy` は Mac 向けのコマンドなので Windows では使えません。また、このコマンドはあくまで「ファイルの内容をクリップボードに送る」ためのものなので、Windows で copy コマンドを使っても代わりになりません。

`testkey` などが存在することを確認したら、VSCode やメモ帳等でファイルを開いて、中身をクリップボードにコピーすれば用は済みそうです。

Comment: `pbcopy` の Windows 版のようなコマンドとして `clip.exe` があるので、これを使えそうです https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/clip

Comment: 質問者さんは `copy` コマンドを `pbcopy` コマンドと同じようなコマンドだと思って使おうとしたのではないかと推測します。実際にはそうではなく、`copy` はファイルをコピーするコマンドであり、Linux で言うところの `cp` です: https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy

Comment: 質問者さんの環境のVSCodeのターミナルは現在PowerShellのようです。なので、 `copy` コマンドは [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.2) のエイリアスとして機能しているようですね。ちなみに、PowerShellには [`Set-Clipboard`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-clipboard?view=powershell-7.2)コマンドレットが存在するようなのでpbcopyやxclipのように使用できそうです。例として `Get-Content C:\Users\user1\.ssh\id_ed25519.pub | Set-Clipboard` が紹介されています。